# What is Eloquent ORM in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I'm a new to the Laravel programming . I found some information from  https://www.quora.com/What-is-Eloquent-ORM-in-Laravel and https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships. But i'm still unable to understand that how i should implement in my project.
Can anyone give me little example about this. Thank you.

Comment: You missed the [Introduction to Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent) in the Laravel Docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Developers can work in Eloquent with multiple databases efficiently using an ActiveMethod implementation. It is an architectural pattern where the model created in the Model-View-Controller (MVC) structure corresponds to a table in the database. The advantage is for models to perform common database operations without coding lengthy SQL queries. Models allow data querying in your tables, as well as inserting new records into tables. The process of synchronizing multiple databases running on different systems is simplified. There is no need to write SQL queries at all. All you have to do is to define database tables and relations between them, and Eloquent will do the rest of the job.

for details https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent
 and other site also help you 
https://stackify.com/laravel-eloquent-tutorial/
https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

From the Lavarel docs:

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple
>   ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each
>   database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact
>   with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as
>   well as insert new records into the table.

See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

> **ORM**: Object-relational mapping (ORM) is a technique for mapping
>   object-oriented systems to relational databases.

Laravel gives their `ORM` technique name `'Eloquent'`. For furthermore read their [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)